# Best app to find duplicates

Tags: apex, appexchange, duplicate-management, findduplicates, duplicate-matching-rule

There are 300,000+ Accounts and 1,000,000+ Contacts . I need to find duplicate Accounts where names can be not exactly matching and might require Fuzzy logic . Later I would need to merge those Accounts. This is a really large number and Salesforce merge process can be very manual and time consuming . Is there an app exchange app or any other custom way to achieve this .

Comment: Have you searched AppExchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5) to find your matches, which includes some fuzzy logic capability, then you can query the [DuplicateRecordSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterecordset.htm) object to observe duplicates and merge them using a small Queueable class:

```
public class MergeDuplicates implements Queueable {
    public static final Decimal SAFETY_BUFFER_DML_STATEMENTS = 0.90; // 90% limits usage. Adjust as necessary.
    // You may also need to account for SOQL limits, CPU time, heap, or other limits.
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        DuplicateRecordSet[] duplicates = [SELECT (SELECT RecordId FROM DuplicateRecordItems) FROM DuplicateRecordSet LIMIT 100];
        // We are done!
        if(duplicates.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        // Get the next item in the list
        DuplicateRecordSet tempSet = duplicates.remove(0);
        // While we're under our limit checks...
        while(Limits.getDmlStatements() < Limits.getLimitDmlStatements() * SAFETY_BUFFER_DML_STATEMENTS && !duplicates.isEmpty() && tempSet != null) {
            Id masterRecordId = tempSet.DuplicateRecordItems[0].RecordId;
            // Choose first item as "master"
            sObject masterRecord = masterRecordId.getSObjectType().newSObject(masterRecordId);
            switch on tempSet.DuplicateRecordItems.size() {
                when 1 {
                    // We're done, go to next or break
                    tempSet = duplicates.isEmpty()? null: duplicates.remove(0);
                }
                when 2 {
                    // We have one duplicate to merge, do so now
                    Database.merge(masterRecord, tempSet.DuplicateRecordItems.remove(1).RecordId, false);
                }
                when else {
                    // We can only merge two items at a time
                    Database.merge(masterRecord, new Id[] {
                        tempSet.DuplicateRecordItems.remove(1).RecordId,
                        tempSet.DuplicateRecordItems.remove(1).RecordId                            
                    }, false);
                }
            }            
        }
        // Go again.
        System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- Always make sure you test logic of this nature before deploying to production. You can cause catastrophic, irreversible damage to your org if you're not careful.
- This code doesn't check all governor limits. You may need to make adjustments to this code.
- There is no error checking here, so you might run in to an infinite loop or crash unexpectedly. Test this code carefully before using in production.

---

There are a [few apps](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=merge%20duplicates) you can check out on the AppExchange. I have not used any of these, and I don't generally provide product recommendations, but feel free to check out your options.

---

Similar to the code above, you could also write a batchable or queueable class that works against a custom Merge Duplicate record. This would allow you to, for example, manually identify the duplicates in an external program, load a CSV of those matches in Salesforce, then run the batch against that, instead. This is slower than a completely automated process, but faster than merging records in the UI. I've actually seen this implemented, though I'm unsure what external program was used to match the data.